# Angular is showing undefined for the data but it is working in the view

Tags: angular8, undefined-behavior

```
weatherData;

getDataFromApi(formData) {
    this.apiService.getWeather(formData.location).subscribe(data => this.weatherData = data)
    console.log(this.weatherData)
  }
```

[image]

This is the function to get data and then store it in a local variable **`weatherData`**, a JSON file is returned from the API.

To get data in the `veiw(HTML)` I'm using
`<p class="item1">{{ this.weatherData?.request.query }}</p>`.

It works fine here but when I need to use the WeatherData for another function then it is showing that the parameters passed is undefined.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in subscribe and check the result.

Comment: if I do that inside the subscribe function then it's giving the data outside it will not recognise data as a variable of the file.

Comment: Try using this `this.apiService.getWeather(formData.location).subscribe((data:any) => {
 this.weatherData = data; console.log(this.weatherData)
})`

Comment: It will show data in the console that is returned from the API but I cannot use the variable - weatherData for further function

Comment: If your data is printing on console. Its impossible that its not assigning on the variable `weatherData`. Can you create a minimal example of this scenario on stackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5pux9

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your code will work asynchronously and the console.log() will be executed before the API call is completed. 
The reason that the data is displayed in view is that you subscribed to the data and it will be streamed to the view asynchronously. The view will be updated only after the API call is complete because of subscription. So you can see the data in the view and not in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and it will work fine.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // getting data for Delhi location
    this.apiService.getWeather("Delhi").subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherData = data;
      console.log(this.weatherData);
    });
  }
```

The reason behind undefined was code works asynchronously. While you send the request compiler move to the next line which was `console.log(this.weatherData)`. It print the value of weather data which was undefined when declaring the variable. When response arrive compiler than assign data with this.weatherData.

Comment: But I don't need data in the console and using this I cannot use the weatherData in other function as outside the subscribe function weatherData is still unavailable.

Comment: weatherData is a global variable. It can be accessed in other function in the same class.

Comment: Check this stackblitz. Click on the button and check console, after clicking the button you can see that data is printing in console. Which means its accessible in whole class. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6zm6x

Comment: I have edited the condition for dataWeather as the condition was always false before. Check it now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6zm6x

Comment: Check my stackBlitz now. The thing which I wanted to show you is `weatherData` is accessible everywhere in the class. But initially it is undefined after the request is successful `weatherData` is replaced with the incoming data.

Comment: But I want to use the provided data at first place. Is there any way to do it ?