# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. angular/firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Running into this error... this is the solution to a previous error i ran into.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59614334/17666012

consent.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.db.getAgents().subscribe((data) => {
      this.agentArr = data
    })
    console.log(this.agentArr)
}
```

database.service.ts

```
getAgents(){
    const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(this.db, 'Agents'))
    const agentCol: any = []
    querySnapshot.then((data) => {
        data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            agentCol.push(doc.id)
        });
        console.log(agentCol)
        return agentCol
    })
}
```

im trying to use the return value from the service function in the consent.component.ts, but then i ran into a error ( above see link ) . this was the solution but this is giving a error as well.... Any help appreciated!

Comment: to me it's not clear what are you trying to achieve and what's the problem you're facing. I think an edit on your question that would bring a little more clarity on these two points would help

Comment: im trying to get the agentCol array from database.service.ts into the consent.component.ts agentArr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to subscribe to a function which not return an Observable.
The getDocs method returns a promise so you could use an RxJS operator called from, with this operator you can convert an promise to an Observable.

Try something like `return from(getDocs(collection(this.db, 'Agents'))`

And import `import { from } from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not returning an Observable and the agentCol is scoped to your Promise block.

You should do something like this:

```
return getDocs(collection(this.db, 'Agents')).asObservable()
```

The asObservable() is to convert your Promise to an Observable.

An other option would be to emit the agentCol with a Subject or BehaviorSubject inside the promise where you now have the return.

In your consent.component.ts you would then subscribe to the Subject

Comment: Error: Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type 'Promise<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>>'